# 外部の非保護コンテンツの読み込みについて

Tags: ssl

SSL対応済のページから外部の非保護コンテンツ（CSSファイルやjsファイルなど）を呼びこむには、非保護コンテンツを内部ファイルとして保存して読み込む以外に方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

まず、 HTTPS でアクセスしたサイトから HTTP のリソースを読み込めない技術的な理由はありません。

しかし「HTTPS のサイトでは全ての通信が HTTPS で行われるだろう」とユーザーは期待しますから、それに反して安全でない通信が行われるという理由で、ブラウザが警告を表示したりブロックしたりします。

よって、**全てのリソースを HTTPS で読み込む**ことがポイントになります。

具体的にはその外部リソースに HTTPS でアクセスできるようにするか、 HTTPS でアクセスできる場所（ HTML と同じ場所など）に移動させるか、どちらかでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

同じドメイン上のファイルであれば同じhttps(ssl)プロトコルで読み込めます。
もし別のドメインのサーバーのhttp(非ssl)のリソースを埋め込むということであれば
ブラウザの警告は出ますが、許可をしたら画像とCSS「だけ」は表示できます。
JSはドメインが違うとセキュリティ上の制限が掛かります。

回避する手段は幾つか有ります。
 ・リソースファイルを同一サーバーにコピーする
 ・リソースのあるサーバーのストレージを設置したいサーバーに
 　マウントしてエリアスを設定する。(同じサーバー内で実ファイルが内部で見えていればエリアス設定だけでも可能)
 ・サーバー上に対象となるリソースファイルへのリバースプロキシを設定する。
 　※相手によってはセキュリティに穴が出来る場合があるので、相手先が信頼できる事が必須です。